# List of string pairs in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

Is there any list-like container that can contain two QStrings per entry?
`QList<QString>` can only contain one QString perentry, but I need something like `QList<QString, QString>`, so when appending to this list I append two QStrings.

Answer (score 4):

```
typedef QList<QPair<QString, QString> > QLinHeaderList;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [std::pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/) of QStrings: `std::pair<QString, QString>`

There is no need to use Qt collection classes rather than the std alternatives unless you want to. for example QString is much better than std::string, but Qt's vector, list, etc are just wrapers around the std versions on most platforms

Comment: Or QPair, if you want to use Qt containers only. I'd define: `typedef QPair<QString,QString> QStringPair` to make things easier.

Comment: @Martin Beckett: No, Qt's container classes are not wrappers around std containers. More about their implementation: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq19-containers.html

Comment: I also don't know where you have this information from... Qt containers don't wrap around anything. Qt even doesn't depend on the standard library, I think (but I'm not sure about that).

Comment: the containers were originally so Qt could support platforms without stl. On newer builds there is an option to use stdlib for all the containers.

Comment: By "option to use stdlib for all the containers" do you mean just using std containers with Qt or compiling Qt so that the Qt containers are just facades for std containers? If you mean the latter, do you have any references for that information, I couldn't find anything about that. I wonder why there would be that kind of option, because it would have required a lot of work to implement and if you wanted to use std containers instead of Qt containers, why not use them directly instead of using them through Qt's container classes.

Comment: @roku - last time I compiled it I thought there was a USE_STL/USE_STD option that use stdlib internally rather than their own implementation - since the platform's stdlib would be well optomised. Personally apart from QString I just use std types/containers

Comment: @roku - on a similar note there was some discussion on replacing signal/slot with boost_signal and skipping the moc. But there was some technical limitation AND of course it's a huge amount of work for little benefit.

Comment: Yes, there is a option called -stl, but I couldn't find out anywhere what it really does. Still I'm pretty sure, that it doesn't change the Qt's container implementation to use std containers.

Comment: -1 That is incorrect. There is no option to make Qt use STL containers internally (and such an option has never existed). Qt containers and STL containers are not fully compatible. For example, `std::list` behaves like `QLinkedList`, not `QList` (QList does not have an STL counterpart). See http://marcmutz.wordpress.com/effective-qt/containers/ for a detailed comparison between Qt containers and STL containers, and how to choose which one to use. Also, see the source code yourself to verify that Qt does not wrap STL: http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qvector.h.html